# what are the right codes to put in my JavaScript to make the buttons work?

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

How to make the other buttons work? I know my JavaScript lacks more codes, I just couldn't figure it out what are the right codes to put. I already tried and searched before posting this. I'm still a beginner. Please respect my post.

Update: already solved it. Thanks!

```js
var i = 0;
function move() {
 if (i == 0) {
  i = 1;
     var elem = document.getElementById("progressBar");
     var p = document.getElementById("p");
     p.innerHTML = i + "%";
     var width = 5;
     var id = setInterval(frame, 40);
     function frame() {
        if (width == 75 ) {
         clearInterval(id);
         i = 0;
        } else {
          width++;
          elem.style.width = width + "%";
          p.innerHTML = width + "%";
        }
     }
      document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";
   }
  }
```

```css
.progress-wrap { margin: 30px 40px; }
h3 { color: #050505; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px;}
button { border-radius: 50%; position: absolute; margin: -27px 0 0 -15px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 8px; background-color: #55efc4;}
.progress { overflow: visible; border-radius: 18px; height: 20px; background-color: #ddd;}
#progressBar { position: relative; overflow: visible; border-radius: 15px; width: 1%; text-align: right; background-color: #55efc4;}
#progressBar:after { position: absolute; content: ''; border-radius: 50%; width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -5px 0 0 -20px; background-color: #55efc4;}
span { position: absolute; color: #050505; margin: -25px 0 0 -15px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="progress-wrap">
  <h3>Photoshop</h3>
  <div class="progress">
 <div id="progressBar" value="75">
    <span id="p"></span>
 </div>
  </div>
  <button id="hide" onclick="move()">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrap">
  <h3>jQuery</h3>
  <div class="progress">
 <div id="progressBar" value="60">
  <span id="p"></span>
 </div>
  </div>
  <button id="hide" onclick="move()">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrap">
  <h3>HTML5</h3>
  <div class="progress">
 <div id="progressBar" value="80">
  <span id="p"></span>
 </div>
  </div>
  <button id="hide" onclick="move()">Click</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I havent run your code myself, but the first thing that catches my eye is that each of your divs and spans share an id.   Ids need to be unique to each other.  they may share a class but ids should be unique.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I will look into this.